# GCP Pub/sub - How to avoid this Key error

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cloud, publish-subscribe, tagging

I am trying to auto tag instances and following one blog. But I am getting key error for everything from user_email i.e, json payload key error, actor key error. I am following this blog https://blog.doit-intl.com/automatically-label-google-cloud-compute-engine-instances-and-disks-upon-creation-5d1245f361c1
I think there might be problem at pubsub/stackdriver end. Is there any way to work it out

```
def hello_pubsub(event, context):
    # parse the pubsub event
    pubsub_message = json.loads(base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8'))
    # pubsub variables
    user_email = pubsub_message['jsonPayload']['actor']['user'].replace('@', '_', ).replace('.', '-')
    instance_zone = pubsub_message['jsonPayload']['operation']['zone']
    instance_name = pubsub_message['jsonPayload']['resource']['name']
    project_id = pubsub_message['resource']['labels']['project_id']

    logging.info(f'new instance created, going to tag instance {instance_name}')
    # tag the instance
    instance_tag = tag_instance(instance_name, project_id, instance_zone, user_email)
    
    # if instance tag was successful and the instance volume list exists
    if instance_tag and instance_tag['instance_disks_list']:
        disks_list = instance_tag['instance_disks_list']
        # tag volumes
        disks_tag = tag_disks(disks_list, project_id, instance_zone, instance_name, user_email)
        if disks_tag:
            return True
```

Comment: Can you check the json structure, please? For example, you can insert (for debug purposes) print(pubsub_message) just next to json.loads, and then you can see in the logs the actual structure of the message.

Comment: Can you share the full error message?

Comment: I agree with @guillaumeblaquiere, could you please share the full error message?

Comment: HI Thanks I resolved the error.

Comment: @Nikhilbrusli How did you resolve the error? Can you post an answer for others to benefit from your solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
pubsub_message = json.loads(base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8'))
```

This returns a json formatted string, not a dictionary object. You need to convert to dict via:

```
data_dict = json.loads(pubsub_message)
```

and then you can process like this:

```
resource_name = data_dict['asset']['name']
print(resource_name)
```